Is there a way to catch @Service initialization errors in Spring Boot
I am currently using Spring Boot with Java 8 using the following snippit in my pom.xml:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

I have a Java Spring @Service, whose initailization can throw an exception:
@Service 
public class FallibleService {
    public FallibleService() throws SomeException {
        /*
            Does something fallible, like opening a file, etc.
        */
        randomOperation();
    }
}

Is there a way to register an error handler for the construction of this object? Specifically, I want the application to close, with a specific error message provided to the user, rather than just spewing an unreadable stacktrace.
I attempted to inline the error management using a try catch block as shown below:
@Service 
public class FallibleService {
    public FallibleService() {
        try {
            randomOperation();
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred!", e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

However, System.exit(0) on my current version of spring. There are ways to fix this, however this doesn't seem idiomatic.

just use @Bean to define your service and do your initialization logic there. Exception in @Bean will stop the program from starting

Use a FailureAnalyzer. Implement one for the specific exception/case you want to handle and provide an error message. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/how-to/application.html#howto.application.failure-analyzer on how to. No need to call exit, if there is an failure during startup (an exception being thrown) the application will stop automatically.

You can handle stuff like this with an ApplicationListener
@Component
@Slf4j
public class FailedListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationFailedEvent> {
    
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationFailedEvent event) {
        log.error(event.getException().getLocalizedMessage());
        // put whatever you want in here
        System.exit(0);
    }
}


User lane.maxwell provided an excellent solution for catching general errors. That is exactly what I was initially searching for, and is more canonical to the original question. Thanks lane!
However, I also located the following solution, which, although requiring the restructuring of my code, was superior for my specific use case. I'm including it here in case anyone else finds it useful.
Alternative method
Remove the@Service annotation, and create a seperate class annotated@Configuration that handles construction:
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FallibleServiceConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public FallibleService fallibleService() {
        try {
            return new FallibleService();
        } catch (SomeException e) {
            // error handling
        }

        // Following code kills spring with exit code -1.
        int code = SpringApplication.exit(this.context, () -> -1);
        System.exit(code);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        this.context = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) context;
    }
}


You bet.  If you find yourself declaring a lot of beans like this manually, you can always employ the EventListener.

You can implement FailureAnalyzer to display failure diagnostic data:

A FailureAnalyzer is used to analyze a failure and provide diagnostic information that can be displayed to the user.

Spring also provides a handy base class to extend from (optionally) - AbstractFailureAnalyzer.
Let's assume the service constructor reads from an application resource file and throws AppResourceNotFoundException, if it's not found. An example analyzer:
public class AppResourceNotFoundAnalyzer extends AbstractFailureAnalyzer<AppResourceNotFoundException> {

  @Override
  protected FailureAnalysis analyze(Throwable rootFailure, AppResourceNotFoundException cause) {
    String rootMessage = rootFailure.getMessage();
    String userDescription = rootMessage + System.lineSeparator().repeat(3) + cause.getMessage();
    return new FailureAnalysis(userDescription, "Make sure you have provided the correct resource path/name", cause);
  }
}

And register the analyzer in META-INF/spring.factories with the full class name:
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=package.AppResourceNotFoundAnalyzer

Spring documentation.
